# Looking to get into AIX for SYSV style unix kernel programming need advice

Tags: aix

Hello Im getting into UNIX kernel programming and I need a system V based Unix, so I chose AIX. My problem basically splits up like this, I need an IBM Power server which I can get, but the latest AIX will also have to run on it so I think it has to be at least a Power 7. So generally I'm looking for a less expensive older model, which is fine for me, all i need is ssh access. My main concern is obtaining AIX itself, I can't seem to find any information on it at all. With Solaris i just needed to have a simple subscription but with IBM it looks more complicated. If i need to pay for a subscription one time that's not a problem. Can anyone inform me of the process for obtaining AIX and any price guidelines or a specific server model that would go good for my purposes?

Comment: Where from do you intend to get the kernel's source/documentation?

Comment: I believe i can debug a live kernel with Dtrace and i have an extremely old version of the source